# Flask-Admin Template

Tags: jinja2, flask-admin

I'm would like to use flask-admin and integrate it in my own layout which is based on flask-bootstrap. I don't care about the navbar that comes with flask-admin would just use the pure list view. I'm struggling to find an elegant solution, such that I don't have to write my own list.html. Structure is:

base.html:

```
{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="container">
       {% block page_content %}
       {% endblock %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

My normal other templates just extend this base.html and overwrite the page_content block. The idea is to have now my own \admin\master.html which should extend the page_content as well. Something like:

\admin\master.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block page_content %}
   {% block body%} here most of the list.html from flask-admin should appear
   {% endblock%}
{% endblock %}
```

It seems that flask-admin in list.html defines also a body block, which seems to overwrite the body block from the flask-bootstrap template. I had the impression that jijna2 templating is somehow hierarchical. e.g. blocks get filled from the direct extension.

I could easily create my own list.html, edit.html and create.html but would probably duplicate most of the code. Is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 1):

I ended copying over everything and creating my own.  I found required changes to most of those files to get things to display properly anyways.